# beforeunload oddities

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer-7

**The problem**

Using `$(window).bind("beforeunload", ...[snip]` to ask if a user wishes to leave the page yields some strange results in some browsers. The dialogue pops up and asks if you wish to stay on the page or leave the page. If you click the stay on the page option, Google Chrome (latest - 13.0.782.215 m) and WinIE7 pops the last history page in the "Back" button.

To illustrate this point, current session history consists of visiting the following pages:

- Page 3
- Page 2
- Page 1

You decide to leave Page 3 and the `beforeunload` event fires. You choose to stay on the current page.

You click the back button again and this time decide to leave the page. You should find yourself at Page 2, but instead you are at Page 1. You can navigate again forward to Page 2 though.

**The question**

How can I prevent the browser from removing these pages from the back button when we choose the "stay on current page" option? Is it possible?

**Example of the problem**

Using Google Chrome, in a new window, head to http://stackoverflow.com and browse a few questions without going back. Then hit the Ask Question button. Begin typing in the dialogue box. Press Back in your browser. Select stay on page. Press back in browser again and this time select the leave page option. You have now gone back two pages in history. You can essentially go back multiple pages if you click stay on page more than once.

**Why does this matter?!**

I don't want to confuse my users. They are not the computer-savvy type.

**My code (not that it is relevant)**

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function(){
    if (in_edit > 0){
        return "You are currently editing this job.\n\nAre you sure you wish to exit the page?";
    }
});
```

Comment: Interesting -- I can reproduce this in Chrome 11 (for example) but not in Canary (version 15). I guess this is/was a bug, but can't find it on http://www.crbug.com.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it in Canary. crbug.com id 93858

Comment: I just tried in Canary again and first time around I *think* I managed to get it to go wrong, but now can't reproduce :(

Comment: Note, `beforeunload` event isn't supported in Opera browser.

Comment: I can reproduce this in Chrome 17 (dev channel & Win 7 64bit), visit this [page](http://jsbin.com/onosij/) and try clicking on back button.

Comment: You can fix this in Chrome with History API's `pushState`, but it's IE7 where you don't have a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chromium resolved the issue in 2012:
You can view the details here:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=93858

Answer (score 0):

You could try to include a hidden iframe into the page and then in the onbeforeunload function change the src on that iframe. 
That could probably include another url in the history that might get removed from the history stack instead of the current page you are on.

So the history looks like this:

```
Page3
Page2
Page1
```

onbeforeunload changes the iframe:

```
Dummy
Page3
Page2
Page1
```

But this is just a guess that might work, you will need to try this...